# smallmatrix with vertical line as column separator, how to do it

Tags: matrices, columns

Since this
`\begin{smallmatrix}[cc|cc] ... \end{smallmatrix}`
is not possible with smallmatrix, I am wondering how can I get a vertical line as column separator in the smallmatrix environment? (smallmatrix does not support alignment parameters like `[c|c]`)
I know the vertical line will probably touch the matrix entries, but that's something I can tolerate.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`smallmatrix` is carefully *not* built on the `array` environment, but directly on lower level primitives and macros. So my best advice is to combine two `smallmatrix` environments

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\left[\begin{smallmatrix}
a & -b \\ -c & d
\end{smallmatrix}\middle|
\begin{smallmatrix}
a & -b \\ -c & d
\end{smallmatrix}\right]
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

write your own environment based on `array`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newenvironment{Smallmatrix}[1]
  {\arraycolsep=3pt\def\arraystretch{0.75}\footnotesize% change to whatever you need
   \array{#1}}
  {\endarray}
\begin{document}

foo $\left(\begin{Smallmatrix}{c|c}
a & -b \\ -c & d
\end{Smallmatrix}\right)$ bar

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: this would look nicer if the minus signs were not included in the centering.  but more important, the gap between content and parentheses is too large (it's wider than the surrounding word spaces).

Comment: then use `{@{}c|c@{}}` ... You already know that ... ;-)

Comment: yes, i know that, but i'm not sure the person who asked the question knows it.